# TFS Visual Studio Test task not populating TRX file

Tags: tfs, automated-tests, azure-devops

We have been using TFS to run automated tests. The tests run either as part of a build or on demand from a Test Plan. We are using Specflow to generate the test scenarios.

For the first month that I was executing these tests, a .TRX file would be generated that contained some logs from specflow. I could also log my own trace logs using System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine. All of that would show up in the .Trx file.

The .TRX file would also show the number of tests that passed, failed, or were inconclusive. If I opened the file in Visual Studio, it would show me a Test Run panel with details on each test and their results.

Recently, however, that stopped happening. The .TRX file is still created, but it is basically empty. It says that no tests were run and all of my Trace logs dont display. TFS still shows me the correct information when I am logged in to the console, but the attached .TRX file is always 2k, meaning its just the skeleton of an xml file.

Here are some details of how we run the tests:

- We have a Test Plan, so the Tests run as part of a Release. The Release contains a single Run Visual Studio Test Task
  [image: Test task configuration]
- The .runSettings file only contains the **TestRunParameters** sections. No other settings are configured.
- We are using TFS 2017 Version 2.

I thought that maybe Specflow had something to do with it, but even a simple MSTest without Specflow wont log correctly.

Some answers have suggested add **/Logger:trx** to the Other Console Options, but that always leaves me with a Warning stating that the Release is running on multiple agents so that settings will be ignored. Our release isnt runnin on multiple agents, so I dont know why I see that warning.

This worked until recently, and I have tried to figure out what has changed. I tried creating a brand new build, new code base, and new tests to run but it doesnt seem to matter.

Let me know what additional information you need. Thanks

Comment: Just try to run the tests via `mstest` command line or `vstest` command line in Visual Studio. Then check if you can get the correct `.trx` file in the TestResults folder something like  `C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\UnitTestProject1\UnitTestProject1\bin\Debug\TestResults`

Comment: @AndyLi-MSFT When I run the Visual Studio Test Task I am able to select Test Run or Test Plan instead of pointing to assemblies. If I run using command line then I have to point to a specific assembly, dont I? I could do this just to see if the .trx file is created, but what if it is? What would that mean? Thanks for the reply

Comment: Just to confirm that if you can run the test locally for now, generally if it doesn't work locally then it will also not work in TFS. Actually the test assemblies are linked to the test cases...  Based on your description it worked before, so just check and compare the differences. Also suggest you cleaning the caches and creating a new build definition to check it that works.

Comment: @AndyLi-MSFT I added an answer that worked for me, but maybe you can explain why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out how to fix the issue, but I dont understand what exactly happened so I hope someone can fill in the blanks.

There are multiple versions of VSTest.Console.Exe on the TFS server. The one that is used when I select **Visual Studio 2017** as the version is

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\vstest.console.exe

I dont know if that is correct or not, but that is what was being used. I noticed that locally I was using a different path.

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\vstest.console.exe

I was able to execute that version of vstest and generate TRX files locally. There is also ANOTHER vstest.console.exe located at

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\Extensions\TestPlatform\vstest.console.exe

I believe that last one is for VSTest V2? Im not entirely sure and would love someone to clarify that.

I believe which executable you run depends on the **Test Platform Version** setting. I normally had it set to Latest, but I changed it to Visual Studio 2017 while trying to figure out why it wouldnt log anymore.

**TLDR - The Solution**

You can, alternately select **Specific Location**, which allows you to provide a path to the executable. I set the **Path to vstest.console.exe** value to C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\vstest.console.exe and everything works fine.

The only thing I can think of is that the version of Vstest under Professional (the version of Visual Studio we are using) is different from the one under BuildTools? The test would run successfully either way, but the executable under Professional also generates the Trx file. Since no details are logged, its hard to tell what is going on.

Hopefully someone can explain what is going on here, but at least anyone who has this same issue has something to try.